# How to create a reactive statement in Svelte with Firebase's onSnapshot?

Tags: firebase, svelte

I'm learning Svelte for the past 4 days and I'm trying to integrate it with Firebase.

I need to listen to a document named after the user's uid after the user logged in which I saved in a writable name userStore.

*Note: My background was React and this can be done easily with useEffect*

I need a way to call unsubscribe in the onDestroy statement... How can I do that?

```
    onDestroy(() => {
        unsubscribe();
    });
```

This is my current code:

```
    $: if ($userStore)
        onSnapshot(doc(db, 'userInfo', $userStore.uid), (doc) => {
            if (doc.data()) {
                console.log(doc.data());
                userInfoStore.set(doc.data() as UserInfo);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `onSnapshot()` returns `unsubscribe`, so it should work like this

```
<script>

    let unsubscribe

    onDestroy(() => {
        if(unsubscribe) unsubscribe();
    });

    $: if ($userStore) {
        unsubscribe =  onSnapshot(doc(db, 'userInfo', $userStore.uid), (doc) => {
            if (doc.data()) {
                console.log(doc.data());
                userInfoStore.set(doc.data() as UserInfo);
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

Is the component destroyed when the user logs out? Because the unsubcription should be called if the user logs out? I think in a component might not be the best place to handle the logic. This would be a way via a custom store

###### userInfoStore.js

```
export const userInfoStore = (() => {
        const initialValue = {}
        const {subscribe, set} = writable(initialValue)

        let unsubSnapshot

        return {
            subscribe,

            startListener(uid) {
                unsubSnapshot = onSnapshot(doc(db, 'userInfo', uid), (doc) => {
                    if (doc.data()) {
                        console.log(doc.data());
                        set(doc.data() as UserInfo);
                    }
                });
            },

            stopListener() {
                if(unsubSnapshot) unsubSnapshot()
            }
        }
    })();
```

###### auth.js

```
onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => {
        if(user) {
            userStore.set(user)
            userInfoStore.startListener(user.uid)
        }else {
            userInfoStore.stopListener()
        }
    })
```

###### App.svelte (main component)

Don't know how important that is or if the listener is stopped anyway when the page is closed

```
<script>
import {onDestroy} from 'svelte'
import {userInfoStore} './userInfoStore'

 onDestroy(() => {
        userInfoStore.stopListener()
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Svelte announced [Runes](https://svelte.dev/blog/runes) for v5 and here's how you could implement it:

```js
export function createUser() {
  let user = $state(null)

  function setUser(value) {
    user = value
  }

  return {
    // We need to use a getter here or the value will always be
    // whatever it is at the time function was called.
    get user() {
      return user
    },
    setUser
  }
}

export function createFirestore() {
  const data = createUser()
  let unsubscribe

  $effect(() => {
    if (data.user) {
        unsubscribe = onSnapshot(doc(db, 'userInfo', data.user.uid), (doc) => {
          data.setUser(doc.data())
        });
    }

    return () => {
        unsubscribe?.()
    }
  })

  return {
    get user() {
      return data.user
    },
  }
}
```

Then import these functions into your svelte component:

```html
<script>
import { createUserFirestore } from './yourFunctions'

const data = createUserFirestore()
</script>

<User user={data.user} />
```

You can of course do all of that logic inside the component.

Note that Svelte v5 has not yet been released and will have changes, but just want to leave this here for future reference.